# Inconsistent behavior when adding new hierarchical tags in Digikam

Tags: tagging, digikam

Whenever I create a *new* hierarchical tag in `Digikam` (right-mouse click on image -> Assign Tag -> Add New Tag) then all hierarchy levels are applied to the image. For instance, if I have the hierarchy `Tag 1 / Tag 2` and add a *new* tag `Tag 1 / Tag 2 / Tag 3` to an image, then all tags `Tag 1 / Tag 2 / Tag 3` are applied to the image.

In contrast, when I add an *existing* hierarchical tag to an image, then only the bottom level is applied. Picking the example from above up, when I add `Tag 3` to an existing image, then *only* `Tag 3` is applied but not `Tag 1 / Tag 2`.

I find this a bit inconsistent, as I now have some images with the full hierarchy and some with the bottom level only.

Is there some way to standardize the behavior of `Digikam`?

Comment: No idea, but KPhotoAlbum gets this right. Unfortunately, AFAIK, there are no utilities to transfer your tags between the two programs, so you're stuck with whichever one in which you invested the tagging effort. If you don't get a good answer here, try their support list: https://mail.kde.org/mailman/listinfo/digikam-users . This does sound like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, it might be the `Toggle Auto` setting of DigiKam.

With the `Captions` pane open, right-click on any one of the tags listed, go down to `Toggle Auto` and choose `Parents`.

Now when you check off a child tag, all of the other tags up the hierarchy also get checked.

(I wanted to send you a screenshot of the menu open but it's not working unfortunately.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This kind of works - at least when you apply a tag using the Captions pane. Good to know that this is a possible way. However, this does not work when going this way: right-mouse click on image -> Assign Tag -> Add New Tag. There, only the child but not the parents are applied.